# Need to convert information from textarea to table

Tags: javascript

I would like know, is it possible to convert this type of information

> 1 AA 146O 07JUL BOSCDG SS1   645P  740A+*      TH/FR   E
>   2 AA 147O 18JUL CDGBOS SS1  1040A 1245P *         MO   E
>   >

to this kind table 
[image]

This is a flight ticket which is building in program Galileo, i would like to convert this info to understandable flight quote. How it's can be done.
I know how to make it if i will enter everything separately, but is it possible to split and convert in one click?

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: "How it's can be done" With code. Try some.

Comment: @j08691 how can i split this text to some variable so i can amke some operations with them

Comment: First you parse the text in the textarea.  A regex may work here, or even just a simple `.split` on the spaces.  Then you figure out what to do with each piece of information.

Comment: Absolutely it's possible.  It'd be possible with the string "tulip" as well.  It all depends on how the data is interpreted.  Some major concerns:  you're parsing what the user types in?  There is a serious risk that the data will not be valid.

Comment: Provide the actual html you are processing and any attempts you made at splitting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting the string up using

> string.split()

Split it on the spaces and it'll give you each section in a variable. For example;

```
var $string = "1 AA 146O 07JUL BOSCDG SS1 645P 740A+* TH/FR E";
$string = $string.split(' ');
```

You can now access each key by using it's array number, for example;

```
console.log($string[2]);
```

Would output ***146O***. Remember the array is 0 based, so this is the third text piece after a space. [0, 1, 2]